# Remove startup (boing) sound in PowerPC Mac Mini G4

Tags: powerpc, apple

I would like to remove the [startup sound](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202768) of my Mac Mini G4 (PowerPC). I know this is possible if I boot from a MacOSX system, however I reformatted my system from the original MacOSX for ppc with a debian/powerpc system.

Is there a way to change that setting from the Open Firmware prompt  (cmd+option+o+f) ?

Ref:

- [Disable boot up sound / dong with no OS/X](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1398604)

Answer (score 0):

pmac-utils (or powerpc-utils from Jessie) has the tool nvsetvol to change the volume of the chime.

ref:

- https://lists.debian.org/debian-powerpc/2019/01/msg00051.html